# Create windows phone package using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-phone-8

I developed a Windows Phone 8 App in Visual Studio 2012 and I'd like to create the Store/App Package. The documentation says I should have a "Project" > "Store" > "Create App Package" menu option, but there is no "Store" option in my "Project" Tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing Windows Phone 8 app in Visual Studio, you don't need to proceed above method. Just run your application.

You will find .XAP file in YourProject/Bin/Debug. Upload the .XAP file. If you are creating Universal apps or Windows Phone 8.1 app, there you may create App Package.